# VB Project unavailable once solution opened in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, solution

I have a VB.NET project under Visual Studio 2010.

Each time I open the solution (which contains only one vb.net project), the solution explorer populates with the associated projects but appends "unavailable" next to the project name. Also, it appends "0 projects" next to the solution name.

Every time I right click and reload the project, it reloads quickly and then reverts back to unavailable.

Whats happens? I have tried to open VS 2010 in administrator mode and I get the same result.

However, If I open a command line prompt window as administrator and from that command line I launch VS 2010 in safe mode using below command:

> devenv /safemode

... and then once VS 2010 opened I open the solution, it works.

So what's the problem?

Comment: Are there tabs at the bottom of the Visual Studio window named "Error list" and "Output"? If so, one of them may reveal an error message.

Comment: @AndrewMorton In error list and output window there is nothing, no error messages (error list window empty and in output window empty). If I reload project, error list window continues empty with no message and in output window says: Operation started. Time, HH:mm:ss, Operation successfully completed. Time HH:mm:ss, Operation started. Time, HH:mm:ss

Comment: As it works in safe mode then, if you have add-ins in your VS2010, have you tried disabling half of them to see if the project then loads? [How to manage add-ins in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11246922/1115360) Otherwise, something in [Visual Studio Solution Unavailable (reload doesn't work)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25853604/1115360) might help.